Why can't I connect to ChatGPT website after a seemingly successful Google authorization?
Before authorization, I can go to the https://chatgpt.com. And after successful authorization via Google, the site does not open and I see this error:



If I erase cookies, I can again log in in unauthorized mode, but after successful authorization it will not open again.
Everything is repeated in incognito mode.
The problem started 2 weeks ago just on the https://chatgpt.com. The only thing that helped was accessing the link containing https://chatgpt.com/auth/login?next=. Now this option has stopped working too.
I am on macOS 12.7.5 with all the latest updates, browsers also updated, computer restarted. I tried connecting different networks.

You're on macos, but you did not state what browser you are using. Are you using Safari? Have you tried Google Chrome? can you see the certificate, and is it valid? Can you test https in other ways?

What certificate are you being served? If you are using a Chromium browser try and use Safari or Firefox

You may want to try clearing all cache and cookies for both Google and ChatGPT. Short of that, not much more anyone here can suggest without knowing what browser you're using and testing a different one like others have mentioned.

Hi! The problem is in Safari and chrome browser. This problem is only with chatgpt.com. On all other sites everything is ok. All work with my account with mobile safari
